# Why am i receiving a "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Tags: c#, filter, datatable

Im trying to process a set of files, i have a given number of txt files, which im currently joining into 1 txt file to apply filters to. The creation of the 1 file from multiple works great. But i have 2 questions and 1 error i cant seem to get around.

1 - Im getting an error when i try to read the newly created file so i can apply the filters. "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

2 - Am i approaching this the correct or more efficient way? by that i mean can the reading and filtering be applied before creating the concatenated file? I mean i still need to create a new file, but it would be nice to be able to apply everything before creating so that the file is already cleaned and ready for use outside the application.

Here is the current code that is having the issue and the 1 commented line that was my other attempt at releasing the file

```
private DataTable processFileData(string fname, string locs2 = "0", string effDate = "0", string items = "0")
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string fullPath = fname;
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(fullPath)))
            //using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open(fullPath,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = sr.ReadLine();
                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                    {
                        string[] headers = line.ToUpper().Split('|');
                        while (dt.Columns.Count < headers.Length)
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add();
                        }

                        string[] rows = line.ToUpper().Split('|');
                        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                        for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count(); i++)
                        {
                            dr[i] = rows[i];
                        }
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }
                }
                //sr.Close();
                sr.Dispose();
            }
            string cls = String.Format("Column6 NOT LIKE ('{0}')", String.Join("','", returnClass()));
            dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = cls;
            return dt;
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return dt;
        }
```

Here is the concatenation method:

```
        private void Consolidate(string fileType)
    {
        string sourceFolder = @"H:\Merchant\Strategy\Signs\BACKUP TAG DATA\Wave 6\" + sfld;
        string destinationFile = @"H:\Merchant\Strategy\Signs\BACKUP TAG DATA\Wave 6\" + sfld + @"\"+ sfld + @"_consolidation.txt";

        // Specify wildcard search to match TXT files that will be combined
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder, fileType);
        StreamWriter fileDest = new StreamWriter(destinationFile, true);

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++)
        {
            string file = filePaths[i];

            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);

            if (i > 0)
            {
                lines = lines.Skip(1).ToArray(); // Skip header row for all but first file
            }

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                fileDest.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
        if (sfld == "CLR")
        {
            clrFilter(destinationFile);
        }
        if (sfld == "UPL")
        {
            uplFilter(destinationFile);
        }
        if (sfld == "HD")
        {
            hdFilter(destinationFile);
        }
        if (sfld == "PD")
        {
            pdFilter(destinationFile);
        }
        fileDest.Close();
        fileDest.Dispose();
    }
```

What im trying to accomplish is reading min(2 or 3 txt files and as much as 13 txt files) and applying some filtering. But im getting this error:
"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Comment: It sounds to me like the first process that creates the merged file, is not releasing resources.. do you have the code for merging the file?

Comment: Please show the code that is **writing** to the file.

Comment: `But im getting this error: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."` On what line of code?

Comment: You are closing and disposing your `fileDest` **after** you want to apply the filters. Remove these 2 lines and place the `StreamWriter` inside a using and only put the for loop in there. Put the rest after that.

Comment: I tried the above suggestions and the combination of the suggestion below and removing the additional lines seem to have gotten me further into the processing.

Comment: It's possible that your anti-virus is opening the file and reading it. Have you tried to do this with the anti-virus (temporarily) disabled?

Comment: Antivirus was not the issue, error has been resolved thank you all for the suggestions.. I believe the true fix was the "using" statement around the creation of the file..   Now my #2 question is what seems to be next as even though everything works now, the file created is still the full unfiltered set of records.. the concatenated file without filters is 34,945 records, it should end up being around 29,240. Where should i place my filtering in order to make sure that the created file is the filtered results?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're disposing the stream reader with the following line

```
sr.Dispose();
```

Using a 'Using' statement will dispose after the stream goes out of context. So remove the Dispose line (if it wasn't clear below)

Comment: I did this and got further, getting an error on my filtering, but im going to try to resolve that one before i post for help.

Comment: The OP is **already** using a `using` for sr. `using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(fullPath)))` This answer can't help (since the OP is **already** doing it). Now, you are right that the `Dispose` is unnecessary (i.e. being done twice). But it won't _hurt_.

Comment: @mjwills In fact, two calls to Dispose might hurt a lot in some bad implementations. There's even a FxCop/StyleCop (cannot remember) rule that tells you to watch out for this

Comment: In theory yes @CamiloTerevinto (although I don't believe in this instance). Nonetheless, the OP is saying that the OP should do something **they are already doing** (if their answer said 'don't do this, it isn't doing anything useful' then it would be defensible - but it still wouldn't solve the OP's current problem). Plus the issue is likely in the _write_ path, not the read path.

Comment: @mjwills I'm aware of that, just wanted to comment that it might actually hurt :)

Comment: @mjwills not sure why the down vote? when this solution worked for the OP? thats if you are the one who down voted it.

Comment: @Rav I can't see the details of the two people who downvoted. Nonetheless, this answer _can't_ have worked for the OP since he / she was _already doing it._ The OP has admitted that the `using` around the _creation_ of the file was the solution - perhaps you could change your answer to reflect that?